# GitLab-CI job fail when having a dependency on a previous manual job

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

#### Situation

Consider the following `.gitlab-ci.yml` example:

```
build:
    stage: build
    script: echo "Building..."

build-doc:
    stage: build
    when: manual
    script: 
        - echo "Building doc..."
        - echo "build result" > output.txt
    artifacts:
        name: "%CI_BUILD_NAME%_%CI_BUILD_ID%"
        expire_in: 1 week
        paths:
            - "output.txt"

deploy-doc:
    stage: deploy
    only:
        - master
    dependencies:
        - build-doc
    script: 
        - echo "Deploying doc..."
        - type output.txt
```

#### Result

The result of this pipeline on the `master` branch is:

[image: gitlab-ci-result]

The log of the `deploy-doc` job says:

```
$ echo "Deploying doc..."
"Deploying doc..."
$ type output.txt
The system cannot find the file specified.
ERROR: Build failed: exit status 1
```

#### Conclusion

Even if the `deploy-doc` has explicitly a dependency on the manual `build-doc` job artifact, the `build-doc` don't get triggered leading to the a fail of the `deploy-doc` job.

#### Question

How can I implement this behaviour correctly? Namely, having a manual job which get triggered when an *automatic* job has dependencies on him?

#### Context

I only want to automatically build **and** deploy the doc on the `master` branch, the other branches can only build the doc manually to download the generated doc.

#### Solution

In addendum to the accepted answer, see my own answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42760945/2501769).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way will be to use a [trigger](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/triggers/). Define the `deploy-doc` job as:

```
only:
  - triggers
```

Use yaml anchors to do two copies of `build-doc` one declared as

```
only:
  - master
```

the other one as

```
when:
  - manual
```

Have the `build-doc` call the trigger when it ends. This will rebuild the whole pipeline so you could define `build` job as

```
except:
  - triggers
```

Or use `$CI_JOB_MANUAL` variable and have `deploy-doc` run only on master and triggers so at least on master it won't rebuild everything.

Comment: Hi @Jakub, Is it possible to use a stage name instead of the job name to make a job dependent on another job? That is, instead of using "build-doc" can I by any chance use "build"?
Thanks.

Comment: @VibhavChaddha I'm not sure what you're asking and how it is connected to this question. But a job that is in next stage will proceed only if previous stage finishes so I think you don't have to change anything.

Comment: Sorry for that but I have also asked it as a separate question. I hope that might help you understand it better. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69278440/can-we-use-a-stage-name-instead-of-a-job-name-to-make-a-job-dependent-on-another

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the *Jackub Kania* answer, which points me in the right direction, I ended up using yaml anchors to solve my problem.

I simply modified the actual `build-doc` to a `.build-doc-template` anchor job (just removed the `manual` condition) and created two version of the `build-doc` job as following:

```
build-doc:
  <<: *build-doc-template
  only: 
    - master

build-doc-manual:
  <<: *build-doc-template
  when: manual
  except: 
    - master
```

This way, I could avoid the *triggers* complication. Ask for full code if needed.