# Can we use a stage name instead of a job name to make a job dependent on another job in .gitlab-ci.yml file?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Is it possible to use a stage name instead of the job name to make a job dependent on another job?

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy
  - tests

build-job:
  stage: build

deploy-feature:
  stage: deploy
  except:
    - master
  when: manual

deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  when: manual

test-cases:
  stage: tests
  dependencies: deploy-feature
```

That is, instead of using "deploy-feature" can I by any chance use "deploy" to make the test-cases job depend on both deploy-feature and deploy-prod jobs? I know that it doesn't work in dependencies but is there anything else with which it might work?

**P.S.** My motive is to run my test-cases job only after any one of the deploy-feature or deploy-prod jobs is successful. As currently, my "deploy" jobs are manual and the "test" job isn't so my "test-cases" job gets executed beforehand.
I can do a "when: manual" in my test-cases job as well and can run it manually after my deploy job but to me, that feels like a workaround and not a solution.
And I have around 17 "tests" jobs so having 2 different jobs for every test-case job is also not a feasible idea.

**Edit:** Although I have accepted an answer, even then if anyone has something more to add or any different solution please do share.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of GitLab 14.3, no, you can't use a Stage in any of the [keywords](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml) where you can use a Job name, however it sounds like your main issue is that your `test-cases` job starts before either `deploy-feature` or `deploy-prod` finish. This is because manual jobs are not treated the same as jobs in the Pending state, so jobs in stages after Manual Jobs can start as soon as the stage is reached, runners are available, or `needs` are met.

You can control this behavior with the `needs` keyword.

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - deploy
  - tests

build-job:
  stage: build

deploy-feature:
  stage: deploy
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == 'main'
      when: never
  when: manual

deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == 'main'
      when: manual

feature-test-cases:
  stage: tests
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == 'main'
      when: never
  needs: ['deploy-feature']

prod-test-cases:
  stage: tests
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == 'main'
      when: manual
  needs: ['deploy-prod']
```

This is a little different from the example in your question since we split up the `test-cases` job into two, one for a 'feature' branch and another for ['main'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64249580/2307873). It is possible to use a single `test-cases` job and have it "need" both deploy jobs, but both would have to complete, which isn't possible given our rule set (which is based on your use of `only` and `except`: we can't have a branch not be `main` and be `main` in the same Pipeline).

One thing I changed is swap `only` and `except` for [`rules`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules). Rules gives us more flexibility since we can define actual `if` conditionals along with OR's and AND's, and we can define multiple conditions with different outcomes. For example, one outcome might be `when: always`, another `when: manual`, and the last `when: never` all in the same job. Also note, according to the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only--except):

```
*only* and *except* are not being actively developed. *rules* is the preferred keyword to control when to add jobs to pipelines.
```

When using rules like this, not only does it control when or why a job will be manual or not, it also controls which jobs are even in the pipeline instance at all. For example, for the `deploy` stage, since we can't have `main` and "not-main" in one pipeline, only one deploy job will ever be in a single pipeline instance. Therefore, if our `test-cases` job "needed" both deploy jobs, it would fail during runtime since it can't find one or the other deploy job. So we have to have one `test-case` job for both pipeline paths.

Comment: Yeah, I had a feeling that using Stage would not be possible. And thank you so much for explaining about rules. I'll now try to use rules instead of except and only. Thank you again and have a great day. :)

Comment: Glad I could help! If my post helped solved the issue, could you mark it as accepted? That way others with similar questions would know there is an answer.